# Same bytecode for method with or without synchronized keyword in method signature

Tags: java, bytecode, synchronized

For the following 2 classes got the same Java bytecode.

java version:

> java version "1.8.0_181" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_181-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

javac and javap version:

> 1.8.0_181

My doubt is

1. shouldn't method with *synchronized* keyword have different bytecode as we can see in *synchronized block* has `monitorenter` and `monitorexit`, or let us assume I should not mix *synchronized block* and *synchronized 
   method* then
2. How does JVM handle both methods differently?

   ```
   public class MySingleton1 {

   private MySingleton1() {}

   private static MySingleton1 ourInstance;

   public static MySingleton1 getInstance() {
       if (ourInstance == null) {
           ourInstance = new MySingleton1();
       }
       return ourInstance;
   }
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   public class MySingleton2 {

   private MySingleton2() {}

   private static MySingleton2 ourInstance;

   public static synchronized MySingleton2 getInstance() {
       if (ourInstance == null) {
           ourInstance = new MySingleton2();
       }
       return ourInstance;
   }
   }
   ```

Bytecode as follows:

```
$javac MySingleton1.java
$javap -c MySingleton1
$javac MySingleton2.java
$javap -c MySingleton2
```

Bytecodes for respective files:

```
Compiled from "MySingleton1.java"
public class MySingleton1 {
  public static MySingleton1 getInstance();
    descriptor: ()LMySingleton1;
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field ourInstance:LMySingleton1;
       3: ifnonnull     16
       6: new           #3                  // class MySingleton1
       9: dup
      10: invokespecial #4                  // Method "<init>":()V
      13: putstatic     #2                  // Field ourInstance:LMySingleton1;
      16: getstatic     #2                  // Field ourInstance:LMySingleton1;
      19: areturn
}
```

and

```
Compiled from "MySingleton2.java"
public class MySingleton2 {
  public static synchronized MySingleton2 getInstance();
    descriptor: ()LMySingleton2;
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field ourInstance:LMySingleton2;
       3: ifnonnull     16
       6: new           #3                  // class MySingleton2
       9: dup
      10: invokespecial #4                  // Method "<init>":()V
      13: putstatic     #2                  // Field ourInstance:LMySingleton2;
      16: getstatic     #2                  // Field ourInstance:LMySingleton2;
      19: areturn
}
```

I just want to increase my understanding of java w.r.t. bytecode.

Let me know as comments if my approach is wrong or if a question is too trivial.

Any reference related to documentation is most welcome except the following:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings

http://www.cnblogs.com/richaaaard/p/6214929.html

Comment: Instead of `$javap -c MySingleton2` use `$javap -v MySingleton2`. This shows me:  `public static synchronized so.MySingleton2 getInstance(); descriptor: ()Lso/MySingleton2; flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNCHRONIZED`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `synchronized` modifier on the method is compiled into the ACC_SYNCHRONIZED flag in the method header. It does not affect the generated bytecode instructions; the code to enter and exit the monitor is added implicitly by the JVM when it sees that flag.

See the [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6) for the complete list of flags in the method header and their meaning.

Comment: Thank you @yole, is it possible to check such flags in bytecode or by some other means? What I want to understand is how JVM know that flag is present at method level? I assume JVM has only bytecode of user, is there anything else (like metadata) also present in bytecode which is not visible/accessible?

Comment: dkb There's a bitfield of flags for each method that includes the synchronized flag. It's the same way the JVM knows whether the method is public or private or strictfip or static or so on.

Comment: The .class file contains a lot of data besides bytecode instructions. See the linked document for a detailed description of the format. All this information is accessible and used by the JVM at runtime.